# How to specify covariates that don't interact with factors when using rstatix package?

Tags: r, anova, rstatix

When adding covariates to a between-subjects ANOVA model specified using rstatix package syntax, can one specify these covariates as having no interaction with the main effects?

For example, results from running the "*RUN1*" code below results in both main effects for the covariates (e.g., "CV1") but also interactions with the "Date" variable (e.g., "CV1:Date) displayed. However, some covariate interactions with the time variable may make no theoretical sense (for example, an individual's gender typically wouldn't change after 6 measurements 1 week apart), therefore, I would like to try and exclude these interactions from the model. "*RUN2*" and "*RUN3*" are some attempts so far to resolve this issue, but didn't work.

Does anybody know how this could be achieved?

My data:

```
MyData <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L), levels = c("5f609c2408813b0009898419", 
"5f9aacf32ab79c000bb1d56e", "5f9feef22ab79c000bb264c8", "5fa48df02ab79c000bb2ec4a", 
"5fa7d6c12ab79c000bb3495d", "5fac7ad22ab79c000bb3d6af", "6003785e2ab79c000978297b", 
"6003a1132ab79c0009782c8e", "6007a18d2ab79c000978526d", "600b9db52ab79c000bcf6d2e", 
"600e2b582ab79c000bcfeebe", "6010990c2ab79c000bd0698f", "6017a8992ab79c000b55eb27", 
"601b29eb2ab79c000b57a8d1", "60ff895fadbe1d0009fd07b2"), class = "factor"), 
    Date = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), 
    MeanValue = c(1.57142857142857, 3, 0.857142857142857, 1.28571428571429, 
    1.42857142857143, 1, 0.714285714285714, 0.142857142857143, 
    1.71428571428571, 0.285714285714286, 1.14285714285714, 1, 
    1.42857142857143, 0.428571428571429, 1.14285714285714, 1.14285714285714, 
    2.71428571428571, 1, 1.71428571428571, 0.857142857142857, 
    1.71428571428571, 0.857142857142857, 0.571428571428571, 1.57142857142857, 
    2.14285714285714, 1, 1.28571428571429, 1.71428571428571, 
    2.57142857142857, 3, 1.14285714285714, 2.57142857142857, 
    1.14285714285714, 1.42857142857143, 1.57142857142857, 1.57142857142857, 
    0.571428571428571, 0.142857142857143, 2.14285714285714, 0.428571428571429, 
    0.714285714285714, 0.714285714285714, 1.28571428571429, 3, 
    0.714285714285714), CV1 = c(43, 56, 73, 43, 49, 52, 52, 33, 
    35, 45, 51, 60, 45, 44, 59, 43, 56, 73, 43, 49, 52, 52, 33, 
    35, 45, 51, 60, 45, 44, 59, 43, 56, 73, 43, 49, 52, 52, 33, 
    35, 45, 51, 60, 45, 44, 59), CV2 = c("1", "2", "2", "1", 
    "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", 
    "2", "2", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "1", 
    "2", "1", "1", "2", "2", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
    "2", "1", "1", "2", "1"), CV3 = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0), CV4 = c(5, 
    5, 1, 1, 2, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 2, 
    5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 2, 5, 5, 4, 5, 
    5, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5), CV5 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), CV6 = c(0, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -45L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And the commands I ran:

```
# Load packages
library(tidyverse)
library(rstatix)

# RUN1: between subjects ANOVA using rstatix
res.aov <- anova_test(data = MyData, dv = MeanValue, wid = ID, within = Date,
                      covariate=c("CV1","CV2",
                                  "CV4","CV5"))
get_anova_table(res.aov)

# RUN2: specify formula
res.aov <- anova_test(data = MyData, dv = MeanValue, wid = ID, within = Date,
                      formula = MeanValue ~ Date + Error(ID/Date),
                      covariate=c("CV1","CV2",
                                  "CV4","CV5"))
get_anova_table(res.aov)

# RUN3: specify formula adding covariates directly in
res.aov <- anova_test(data = MyData, dv = MeanValue, wid = ID, within = Date,
                      formula = MeanValue ~ Date + CV1 + CV2 + CV4 + CV5 + Error(ID/Date))
get_anova_table(res.aov)
```